# Python OpenCV libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: python, opencv, libpng

Have a face_recognition code and trying to change the BGR of some images. Running the code with this line: `python3 encode_faces.py --dataset dataset --encodings encodings.pickle`. There is a way to bypass the error from below:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /tmp/opencv-20180529-55469-97fkx6/opencv-3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 11115
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encode_faces.py", line 38, in <module>
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /tmp/opencv-20180529-55469-97fkx6/opencv-3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:11115: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

This is my source code:

```
# import the necessary packages 
#asa s ruleaza 
# python3 encode_faces.py --dataset dataset --encodings encodings.pickle
from imutils import paths
import face_recognition
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input directory of faces + images")
ap.add_argument("-e", "--encodings", required=True,
    help="path to serialized db of facial encodings")
ap.add_argument("-d", "--detection-method", type=str, default="cnn",
    help="face detection model to use: either `hog` or `cnn`")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# grab the paths to the input images in our dataset
print("[INFO] quantifying faces...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))

# initialize the list of known encodings and known names
knownEncodings = []
knownNames = []

# loop over the image paths
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    # extract the person name from the image path
    print("[INFO] processing image {}/{}".format(i + 1,
        len(imagePaths)))
    name = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the input image and convert it from RGB (OpenCV ordering)
    # to dlib ordering (RGB)
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # detect the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding boxes
    # corresponding to each face in the input image
    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb,
        model=args["detection_method"])

    # compute the facial embedding for the face
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

    # loop over the encodings
    for encoding in encodings:
        # add each encoding + name to our set of known names and
        # encodings
        knownEncodings.append(encoding)
        knownNames.append(name)

# dump the facial encodings + names to disk
print("[INFO] serializing encodings...")
data = {"encodings": knownEncodings, "names": knownNames}
f = open(args["encodings"], "wb")
f.write(pickle.dumps(data))
f.close()
```

Print(image.shape) error=

```
[INFO] quantifying faces...
[INFO] processing image 1/1401
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
(1080, 1920, 3)
[INFO] processing image 2/1401
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encode_faces.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(image.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: can you print image.shape after you read it

Comment: Updated the question flow. there is no attribute 'shape'

Comment: it looks like there is something wrong with the second image maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there was an error with the photos. They had to be recalibrated. DId run another script to save the photos in order to create a new dataset. It worked 2nd time.